# Nothing being printed out

Tags: java

I'm very new to programming and I'm having a bit of trouble. Basically what I'm trying to do is to have the findCar method loop through the LinkedList called cars and have it printout the ids of the car objects. It will compile however nothing is being printed, could someone please explain why this is?

Here is the main class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CarManger {
private LinkedList<Car> cars = new LinkedList<Car>(); 

public void setup()

{   
cars.add(new Car(1));
cars.add(new Car(2));
cars.add(new Car(3));   
}

public void main() {

    char choice;
    while ((choice = readChoice()) !='x' ) {
        switch(choice) {
            case 'a': findCar(); break;
        }
    }
}

private char readChoice() {
    System.out.print("Your choice: ");
    return In.nextChar();
}

public void findCar()
  {
    for (Car i: cars)
   { 
    int value = i.getId();
    System.out.println(value);
   } 
  }

 }
```

And here is the Car Object

```
public class Car {

private int id;

public Car(int id) 
{
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
} 
}
```

And here is the In class for gathering input

```
import java.util.*;

public class In
{ private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String nextLine()
{   return in.nextLine(); }

public static char nextChar()
{   return in.nextLine().charAt(0); }

public static int nextInt()
{   int i = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    return i;   }

public static double nextDouble()
{   double d = in.nextDouble();
    in.nextLine();
    return d;   }
```

Here is also the revised code

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;

  public class CarManger {
   private LinkedList<Car> cars = new LinkedList<Car>(); 


  public static void main(String [ ] args) {

    CarManager carManager = new CarManager();
     }

public CarManager () {

    setup();
    main();

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `setup()` method is never called, and so no Cars appear to be added to your cars list.

Note that your main method needs to be static and to have an array of Strings parameter (unless this is not the starting point main method for your program). Without a main method, the program will compile, but won't run.

I suggest that you create a valid main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

And inside create a CarManager object, call `setup()` on it, etc...

Note: if I had a method called `findCar()`, I'd probably have it accept a parameter, here, the best parameter would likely be an int to represent the Car's id number, I'd declare the method to return a Car object, and inside the method body, I'd search for a Car whose id matched that of the method parameter. The method signature would look something like this:

```
public Car findCar(int id) {
   // TODO: 
   // write code to loop through the cars list 
   // if we find a car whose getId() matches our parameter id int
   // return it!
}
```

Your main method would look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CarManager carManager = new CarManager();

    // here you'd call methods on carManager
    // for instance if CarManager had an addCar(...) method

    Car car = new Car(4);
    carManager.addCar(car);
}
```

Note, I'm not calling your current `setup()` method or `readChoice()` because they don't look right to me, but without your specific assignment requirements, it's hard to guess.

Comment: ah, so I need to call it at some point for it to add the cars? It's the simplest things that are overlooked :P thanks Hovercraft, from what you can see there wouldn't be any other problems or improvements you could suggest?

Comment: @Mark: see edit. Your code shouldn't run as written since there is no valid main method.

Comment: I've added     

         public void main(String [ ] args) {
         setup();
         main(); 
       }


However the compiler is now saying I  "non-static method setup() cannot be referenced from a static context"

How would I go about working around that?

Comment: @Mark: that code shouldn't compile since you're calling setup and main as if they were static and they're not, nor should they be. As I noted above, in your static main method, you must create a CarManager instance and then call methods on this instance.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full of Eels Would you be able to provide an example of how that is done? I tried doing it with a root class but that didn't work. Sorry to be a bother, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Mark: how *what* specifically is done? What are your requirements, what exactly has you stuck? Do you know how to createa CarManager instance? That's easy: `CarManager carManager = new CarManager();`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how you in code in the static main method create a CarManager instance, I've tried and the compiler keeps telling me it cannot find the CarManager method.

Comment: @Mark: see edit. I'm still quite confused as to what your requirements are. Your CarManager methods look off to me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels my static main method looks like this now:

`public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        
        CarManager carManager = new CarManager();
    }`

And just below is 

     `  public void CarManager () {
    
        setup();
        main();
    
    }`

But now the compiler is saying it cannot find symbol - class CarManager
Are there other lines of code I need to properly describe the class?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29433135/edit). Note that constructors have no return type declared, not ***void***, not anything.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, new to this site. I've done what you said and the revised code is at the bottom of the question.
@HovercraftFullOfEels However the compiler is telling me CarManager() needs a return type, hence why I put void there before. I don't mean to try your patience and I do appreciate the help but I was hoping you might be able to point me in the right direction regarding why this might be happening/ what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your time btw

Comment: @Mark: The compiler is non-forgiving, so check spelling and capitalization carefully: CarManger != CarManager. Your constructor name must match the class name **exactly**. You still haven't informed us of your specific requirements.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ah, sharp eyes haha
Well my requirement is that I just wanted to have the findCar() method in CarManager printout the Id's of the 3 cars as an exersize in instances and linked lists. Is that what you mean by specific requirements? Sorry for being a noob

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining the main method correctly. It should be like this:

```
public static void main(String [ ] args)
```

Also, you should call the `setup()` method to load the array of cars.